# Can quill limit the size of upload image?

Tags: quill

As the image is large, the response is slow, so must limit! How to do it?  thanks!

```
var editor = new Quill('#postContent', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: '#toolbar-container'
  },
  theme: 'snow',
  //placeholder: '不超过3000字...',
});
```

Comment: may my answer on this question help you
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41888453/4683616)

Answer (score 6):

Sure can, I made a Quill module to *compress* images once they are added to the Quill editor (Pasted, Uploaded, Dragged). You can adjust the compression and quality of the compression too.

https://github.com/benwinding/quill-image-compress

```js
import ImageCompress from 'quill-image-compress';

Quill.register('modules/imageCompress', ImageCompress);

const quill = new Quill(editor, {
  // ...
  modules: {
    // ...
    imageCompress: {
      quality: 0.7, // default
      maxWidth: 1000, // default
      maxHeight: 1000, // default
      imageType: 'image/jpeg', // default
      debug: true, // default
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've only one problem: when I paste an image, the original one stays in the editor and the resized one appears below it. Also, the toolbar button to add an image no longer works (nothing happens and there are no errors). I'm using version 2.0.0-dev.3 of Quill.js.

Answer (score 2):

Yes he can. When you add your image, use :

```
quill.insertEmbed(0, 'image', value, 'user'); // to insert the image

quill.formatText(0, 1, 'width', '300px'); //to limit the width
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at the moment, you would have to create a custom [image handler](http://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/#handlers). Feel free to open a [feature request](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/).

Answer (score -1):

I gave him this solution, it is not the right one, but it works temporarily:

I modified quill.js and add this validation:

```
var maxSize = 2097152; // Maximum limit of 2mb (2,097,152 kb)
var fileSize = fileInput.files[0].size;
if (fileSize <= maxSize) { .... }
```

Image example of quill.js:

[image]

Comment: Post the code instead of the picture. It will be easier to copy the relevant code.