# Upload image on server and add file path inside image tag using quilljs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, cakephp, quill

I am using `quilljs` for my editor. All my data are handle by mysql database. I am using `Angularjs 1.x` and for backend `Cakephp` is my frame-work. 
I am currently trying to build a forum kind of page in which I want to save multiple images along with text which will be formatted using quilljs

```
<p>sd<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgA....SUVORK5CYII=" alt="i am image"><b>it is image of earth</b></p>
```

This is what currently storing in my database. Now if there is multiple big images come in then size of field will be too much high there for I want to upload image inside severside folder and want to print image address inside image tag like:

```
 <p>sd<img src="../img/709f2d0be9d13c645037f1b9bb066b00a6d7/image1.jpg" alt="i am image"><b>it is image of earth</b></p>
```

So I can fetch image directly from given folder.

Comment: What is the question?  Perhaps something about uploading images using those packages?  Or something else?  Or about base64?  Maybe specific to Quilljs, not relevant to MySQL?

Comment: my requirement are 1) store formatted text(which is html format) within mysql which is done 2) currently in img tag it stores image in base64 format which exceed my database length so i want to store it in some specific folder and the path of that image need to print with image tag in html , so i can store that html along with img tag 

i hope you understood my point.

Comment: If your images are so big that you are hitting MySQL limits, you are better off storing the image in a file (outside MySQL) and simply put the link to in the `<img ...>`.  (I can help with MySQL, but not with cakephp/etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i have done small trick with quilljs. i have put some code inside quilljs which send image toward my php script on line number 8663 after `if (typeof value === 'string')` this statement i have added script which sends image value to my php script

```
var img = {
                'img' : value
            }
            $.ajax({
                    url: "../Writers/writerCertificateupload",
                    data: img, 
                    contentType: undefined,
                    type: 'post'
           }).success(function(path){
                node.setAttribute('src', path);
            })
```

where `node.setAttribute('src', path);` sets path which i am returning from php script it sets it on image tag i.e `<img src="../img/709f2d0be9d13c645037f1b9bb066b00a6d7/image1.jpg">`
and then it sets it inside editor and then we can save that data within editor. this is how i have solve this problem.

my php code is

```
        public function writerCertificateupload()//pending
    {
            $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
            $this->autoRender=false;
            define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'files/post/');
            $img = $_POST['img'];
            $img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
            $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
            $data = base64_decode($img);
            $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.jpg';
            $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

            $file = "../".$file;
            print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
    }
```

Comment: i am also facing similar problem but using laravel as backend.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create custom image handler ([like here](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/863#issuecomment-240579430)) and check base64 string length with [fileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Comment: i have used your suggestion it helped me but i am facing another probelm with image uploading. i tried to upload image using angular and javascript respectively but in both case it is not working . so my problem remains same

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Angular(primeNg) and ended up with the below solution, Btw plz notice that you only need to monitor the editor text change and do some modification like below:

```
public async handleTextChange(event: any) {
try {
  const operations = event.delta.ops;
  for (let i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) {
    const op = operations[i];
    const opType = Object.keys(op)[0] as any;
    if (opType == 'insert' && op['insert'].hasOwnProperty('image')) {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const uploadedImageURL = await this.uploadImage(op['insert'].image);
      this._cdr.detectChanges();
      const newContent = event.htmlValue.replace(
        op['insert'].image,
        uploadedImageURL
      );
      this.editorContent = newContent;
      this.contentChanged.emit(newContent);
    }
  }
} catch (error) {
  this.editorContent = this.editorContent + '<br/><br/>';
} finally {
  this.isLoading = false;
  this._cdr.detectChanges();
}
```

The upload method will be like this, by the way the upload logic will be depends on your own logic though more or less it's the same:

```
async uploadImage(dataURL: string): Promise<string> {
    const ImageData: FormData = new FormData();
    let fileType = dataURL.substring(
      dataURL.indexOf(':') + 1,
      dataURL.lastIndexOf(';')
    );
    let fileExtension = fileType.split('/');
    const file = new File(
      [dataURL],
      `file${new Date().getTime()}.${fileExtension[1]}`,
      { type: fileType }
    );
    ImageData.append('file', file);

    const uploadedImageURL = await this._imageUploaderService
      .uploadedImage(ImageData)
      .toPromise();

    return uploadedImageURL ;  
  }
```

The component html would be like this

```
<p-editor
  name="editorContent"
   [(ngModel)]="editorContent"
   [id]="editorId"
   [style]="{ height: '320px' }"
   (onTextChange)="handleTextChange($event)"
   ></p-editor>
<app-spinner *ngIf="isLoading == true"></app-spinner>
```

It's worth mentioning that I used this for p-editor which belongs to primeNg in angular projects